# How to change the default message.properties

Tags: grails, internationalization

Let's say we have the following line of code:

```
<p>    <g:message code="nav.usuario.show"  />    </p>
```

If we are using an italian computer, Grails will look at `messages_it.properties` first. If grails desn't find `nav.usuario.show=textLabel` there, will try to find it in `messages.properties`. I want to **change this behavior to look at** `message_es.properties` **instead the default** `messages.properties` (but **only if the label is not in the current locale language**)

I tried the following code, but I didn't see any change. `resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {   
    localeResolver(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver) {
        defaultLocale = new Locale("it","")
        java.util.Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale)
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply copy the code of the language you want by default (for example `messages_es.properties`) to the default `messages.properties` file.

If you want to keep the English language, you have to create a new file with a name like `messages_en.properties`. Move the code of `messages.properties` there.

Comment: Actually, in the following code, when the default property could be useful? `<g:message code="some.label" default="Some Text" />` @dmahapatro @crudolf ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix the locale, put the following lines into the init closure of your `BootStrap.groovy`:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"))
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("it"));
```

or

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("es"));
```

Comment: I don't want to fix the locale. I want to use the locale of the computer-browser. I want to change the defult `messages.properties` when the label is not found in the current locale messages. It is better explained in my question!

Answer (score 0):

```
beans = {   
    localeResolver(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver)   
}
```

Then setup a filter to change the default locale based on the request.

```
//Filter
class LocaleFilters {
    def localeResolver

    def filters = {
        localize(controller: '*') {
            before = {
                 Locale.setDefault(localeResolver.resolveLocale(request))
                 return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the local context is `Spanish` then the default sets to `_es`, so on an so forth for other locales based on which locale the application is accessed.

Comment: I think I don't understand you. The code you posted looks the default Grails behavior, is it? I want to change the default language if the local language is not found!

Comment: The solution came to my mind right know. I think it is so easy! I just didn't realize. I'll post it.