# Spring MVC 4 with Spring boot and thymeleaf - i18n not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, internationalization, thymeleaf

I'm trying to make a simple internationalization example in spring mvc 4 with spring boot, but it's not working. Here is my web app structure

[image]

And here's my java configuration:

```
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        Locale defaultLocale = new Locale("en_US");
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(defaultLocale);
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new
                LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

My Thymeleaf page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initialscale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Home</title>

    <!-- CSS Links -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <p th:text="#{welcome}">Hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I defined welcome message in both messages properties files, and I put the following in the application.properties file:

```
spring.messages.basename=messages
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
```

when I hit localhost:8080/home, it prints out ??welcome_en_us??.
I don't know what i have missed. And I found some people writing the basename as "classpath:messages', what does that mean? I mean isn't my project structure right and should put the properties files elsewhere?

Comment: Add a `messages.properties`.

Comment: Your project structure seems fine, `src/main/resources` is a Source Folder i.e. folder in `classpath`. I don't understand what is the issue here, what are you expecting to happen? and what is the actual output?

Comment: Exactly as M. Deinum mentioned, if you add file messages.properties into resources (file could be even empty) it will start working

Comment: thx all .. yes you are right, as @M.Deinum said, it works fine now. but if i may ask, why does it require that, specially that I defined a default locale to use en_US properties file? should I remove the en_US file and consider the messages.properties the default english (i mean why duplicate)?

Comment: let me know what version of `Thymeleaf` are you using? because i am using same structure and it doesn't working for me.

Comment: I took this as a starting point in order to implement my own LocaleResolver.
I learned that the WebConfiguration's @Bean method must have the name "localeResolver". Otherwise it would not work for me.
(Running Thymeleaf 3.0.2 and Spring Boot Starter Parent 1.4.3)

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody intends to post an answer for this question I post one.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18624807/8583692) (just the answer!) is related to your problem.

It says that you put messages of your default language (whether it is English or not) in the *messages.properties* and make specific file for your other locales.

In case *messages.properties* is not for English, then make a *messages_en.properties* file for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I had application.properties and messages.properties file. I removed application.properties file, I was not using it.
After removing "application.properties" file, it worked for me.